# Applicable force at constant velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

For a body moving at a constant velocity, the force $F_{net}=ma$

Since acceleration is 0, $F_{net}=0$ (i.e force applied = resisting force)

Since force applied and resisting force are equal, will the body move?
If so, what amount of force must be applied?

Comment: You're stating that the body is moving at a constant velocity and then you're asking if it will move?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Remember that force doesn't cause motion, it causes *changes* in motion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient background or research. Any introductory text on Newton's Laws of motion covers this question extensively.

Answer (score 2):

When the net force is zero, all you can tell is that the body will remain in the same state of motion (ie. same velocity).

If the object is at rest and the force applied is equal to the resisting force, the object will remain at rest : the velocity remains zero. An example of this : someone pushing on a parked car. The static friction exerted by the asphalt on the tires will balance the human force exerted on the car.

If the object was moving already (ie. some unbalanced force put it in motion in the past but was balanced since then), the object will remain in motion at the same velocity. An example of this : someone falling with an open parachute. Gravity is the applied force and air friction is the resisting force.

Finally, please let me say that the terms "applied force" and "resisting force" can be misleading. For instance, is you drop a ball and it falls down, gravity could be seen as an "applied" force but if you throw the ball up, gravity will actually slow down the ball.

In the above, I chose only 1D situations where there were two opposing forces and your chose of words can be used without too much harm. In a 2D or 3D situation, you may have 3 (or more) non parallel force, some playing the "applied" and "resisting" roles at the same time.